# Store encrypted text potentially containing \u0000 in Supabase Postgresql database

Tags: postgresql, supabase, supabase-database

Trying to store encrypted text using crypto-js AES in Supabase Postgres database, I want the encoded string to be as short as possible, so I convert the base64 result from the encryption function using `atob` to a binary string, as it occupied less characters. I then want to store this result in the Supabase Postgres database, but sometimes the encrypted binary string consists \u0000, which triggers the error `ERROR: unsupported Unicode escape sequence Detail: \u0000 cannot be converted to text.` I was told that [PostgresSQL does not plan to suport \u0000 as nul-terminated strings is used a lot in the backend](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/8239.1500489054%40sss.pgh.pa.us).

my encryption and decryption function:

```
export function encryptText(text, key) {
  return window.atob(AES.encrypt(text, key).toString());
}

export function decryptText(text, key) {
  return AES.decrypt(window.btoa(text), key).toString(enc.Utf8);
}
```

Is there any other way to achieve my goal of storing encrypted text inside Supabase Postgres with as little character as possible?

I've tried assing `.trim()` after the text is encrypted, to remove any trailing \u0000.

I've also thought about replacing \u0000 with other characters, but I if I do so, how can I accurately un-replace it before I call the decryption function?

Comment: Well don't store it as a `text` string. Store it as a `bytea`

Comment: Similarly, your JS should not return a `string` but a `Buffer` or `Uint8Array` for the encrypted value. You really should not treat binary data as text.